# How to RegEx match double underscore, but not single ( __ not _)

Tags: javascript, node.js, stylelint

I'm working on a stylelint rule for modified BEM, which is essentially saying that a single underscore is not allowed, but a double underscore is.

match case:

- `foo__bar`

non-match cases:

- `foo_bar`
- `foo_bar__baz`

I would (ideally) like not just a working code snippet, but an explanation of how a problem like this is best solved using only JavaScript RegEx

Here are the relevant docs for stylelint: https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/selector-class-pattern/

Here is a test suite that would need to pass: https://regex101.com/r/NjwOa3/3/tests

Comment: What does a Stylelint rule look like? Can you give a template example? **Show us how far you got**.

Comment: @tadman updated the question

Comment: @tadman I just realized that I what I needed was actually different from what I asked (it needs to also match on no underscores). Should I ask a different question or update this one? The given answer does indeed work for what I asked

Comment: If you got a satisfactory answer, accept this one and re-post with more specifics. As a note, try and give more examples. Like I'd want to know if `foo___bar` or `__foo_bar` counts or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a regular expression like below.

```
^[^_]*_{2,2}[^_]*$
```

or try this for matching only the double underscores.

```
_{2,2}
```

Comment: For "two or more" you may want `__+` Not sure why you didn't do `__` as that's probably easier than `_{2,2}`.

Comment: it has to be exactly 2. We wound up not using regular expressions in the end